Does anyone know what is this number?
Answering this question, @user64494 came with a very nice answer.
My problem is that the front factor is
   HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, -1]

With an absolute error of $2.6\times 10^{-8}$, the $ISC$ proposes $$\sim  \frac 1 {10}\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \,\,\Gamma    \left(\frac{13}{20}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{31}{40}\right)}$$
Is anyone able to identify it ? This is just for the sake of the art sake.

Clearly Yes exist closed-form. Using AskConstants
$$\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};-1\right)=\cosh ^{-1}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \sec
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)$$
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 700}, 
N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, -1] - 
ArcCosh[1 + Sqrt[2]]*ArcSec[2^(1/4)], 200]]

(* 0.*10^-887 *)

Update:
Using Maple 2024:
simplify(evalc(Re(convert(hypergeom([1/2, 1/2, 1, 1], [3/4, 5/4, 3/2], -1), elementary))))
gives:
$$2 \arcsin \! \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}\right) \left(-\ln \! \left(2\right)+\ln \! \left(\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}+2^{\frac{3}{4}}\right)\right)$$

How long did it take to return the output?

@azerbajdzan On my low end computer 170 seconds.

Can you do the same with HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,1,1},{5/4,7/4},-1] and HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,2/3,1,7/6},{11/12,17/12,3/2},-1]? I am not sure I can manage to install the tool. It is also quite big 600MB zipped.

@azerbajdzan, no need to use AskConstants! Using FunctionExpand: FullSimplify@FunctionExpand@HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1}, {5/4, 7/4}, -1] gives a nice expression :)

Just a mountain of thanks

@Domen I am aware of that I just did not try it, but for the second case it does not work neither for OP constant.

@MariuszIwaniuk. If I may ask another favor, could you expand HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1/2 + 1/(2*n), 1 + 1/(2*n)},    {3/2, 3/4 + 1/(2*n), 5/4 + 1/(2*n)}, -1]/  (ArcCosh[1 + Sqrt[2]]*ArcSec[2^(1/4)]) as a shor series and tell me what are the first coefficients ? Thanks in advance.

@ClaudeLeibovici Asymptotic[  HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1/2 + 1/(2*n), 1 + 1/(2*n)}, {3/2,      3/4 + 1/(2*n), 5/4 + 1/(2*n)}, -1]/(ArcCosh[1 + Sqrt[2]]*     ArcSec[2^(1/4)]), {n, Infinity, 1}] give me:HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, -1]/( ArcCosh[1 + Sqrt[2]] ArcSec[2^(1/4)])

@azerbajdzan $$, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};-1\right)=\frac{3 \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2
\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} \log \left(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2
\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)\right)}{2\ 2^{3/4}}$$,for: HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2,2/3,1,7/6},{11/12,17/12,3/2},-1] AskConstants and Maple Fails.

Thanks again ! Would you get anything doing {n, Infinity, 2}] or more ?

Clearly no.
   N[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, -1], 64]
   0.8741268390368287270525776890493684248126217635582897428794914747

   N[1/10 (Gamma[1/8] Gamma[13/20])/Gamma[31/40], 64]
   0.8741268129594580557535792112246672815907840597914766996278009398


Piggybacking on Mariusz's answer, I used AskConstants to find closed forms of $\, _4F_3\left(\ldots;\ldots;-x\right)$ for $x = 1/4, 1/2, 1$. After massaging the results at noticing patterns, it seems that
$
\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};-x\right)=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2 x \left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)}\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2 x
   \left(-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$
for all complex $x$ away from the negative real line.
Functions to compare:
pFq[x_] := HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1, 1}, {3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, -x]
formula[x_] := 
  ArcTan[Sqrt[2x(1+Sqrt[1+1/x])]]ArcTanh[Sqrt[2x(-1+Sqrt[1+1/x])]]/(2Sqrt[x])

Some series terms:
Series[pFq[x], {x, 0, 3}]


PowerExpand[Normal[Series[formula[x], {x, 0, 3}]], Assumptions -> x > 0]


Some numerical verification:
Plot[{pFq[x], formula[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3], Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Dashed]}]



A better version of the formula (ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x - Sqrt[x^2 - x]]] ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x^2 - x]]])/(2 Sqrt[x]) which works for x<=1, i.e. in the whole range where the original hypergeometric function is real.
